# Do a geocoding Request as User/Guest, not the Server

Tags: jquery, ajax, maps, geocode

I'm currently building a small commnunity where users can mark specific positions on a map.

To save the Map points I need to save lat/lng to my database, but the user don't know lat/lng, so I have to use the (reverse) geocoding API.

I've looked into geonames.org but the results of the Fulltext-Search is...well not so good. If i search for "München" for example I get about 5 Results with the same title/name.

Testing the same City in Google Maps Api, the results are much better, so i want to use the Google Gecoder.

The only problem left is, on the documentation page there's a limit mentioned - max 2500 requests/day.

Well that sounds a lot, but if my Community gets bigger it's not that much...

So my question is, is it possible to do a Geocode Request to Google Maps Api using the Guests IP-Address, so Google don't count it as request from my server?

Currently "my way" to geocode something is to get a seperate PHP file through AJAX (jQuery) while passing the search string to it. The PHP file then get the results with "simplexml_load_file", and then give it back to the main document.

If you look at this Geocoder: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/

You can see in the Footer this description: "This form uses JavaScript-On-Demand (JSON) code that causes your Web browser to be the one making the request (rather than gpsvisualizer.com), which means your queries don't count against my server's limit."

Comment: You should use the javascript api if you want to geocode from the client. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: So if i use the "Javascript Way", Google thinks the request is done by the guest?

Comment: Yes, because it IS done by the guest.

Comment: Yes, it is done by client but it does not mean it s not using your quota. The visitor still request by your URL and API key etc. so it still uses your quato. I don t think there is a way for this.

Comment: @KevinB It looks like the Google Maps JavaScript library builds a request with a signature token, probably based on the API key. It's quite possible that client-side JS queries do count against your domain/key limit, since the heavily-obfuscated Google Maps library knows your key and domain.

Comment: But i dont understand how "http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/" ist doing that? It's a free geocoder and i've never hit the request limit using it! Some magic is going on here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Short: no, sorry.

Alternative: you may use the javascript geolocationAPI of the browsers (as far as they are supported) to get the coordinates. That allows you to use, for example, the google geocoder api. Some starting point might be here: [support and link page](http://www.browsergeolocation.com/)

Note: A user might use the google map widget to mark their own position, where you can retrive the coordinates too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how/why is it working on "http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/" ? I don't get it... geolocation of the browser is no option, i don't need the position of the user, i need the position of maybe Paris, France because the user was on holiday there.

Comment: the [google geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) documentation describes how a string is used to get the location coords in the first paragraph "What is Geocoding?". In the next section it shows the "Required parameters", and explains coords->address und address->coords.

Comment: a similar link is on your provided "gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/" url to the outdated Yahoo! Geocoding API used by that specific project.

Alternative: There are lists of city coords available on the net.

Comment: As answered above, it IS possible, it's all in the Jungle of Google Help Pages, you just need to find it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i've found something. It seems that **Kevin B** was right.

Look at this: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat?hl=de

According to that...

> When to Use Client-Side Geocoding
>
> The basic answer is "almost always." As geocoding limits are per user
>   session, there is no risk that your application will reach a global
>   limit as your userbase grows. Client-side geocoding will not face a
>   quota limit unless you perform a batch of geocoding requests within a
>   user session. Therefore, running client-side geocoding, you generally
>   don't have to worry about your quota.

... it IS possible, simply using the Javascript API!

The User searches for "Paris, France", the Google JS API returns lat/lng, i store it in the DB (Caching) and show it on a Google Map, so i don't need any Server-Side Geocoding-Request!